# I need this function in php

Tags: php, node.js

I need to convert this function of `nodejs` to be converted in `php`.
Your help will be appreciated!

```
var captcha = sliderCaptcha({
  verify: function (arr, url) {
    var ret = false;
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(arr)
    }).then(function (result) {
      ret = result;
    });
    return ret;
  },
  remoteUrl: "api/Captcha"
});
```

Comment: any help is appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? PHP does not contain any core concept of sliders

Comment: nevermind... i found a workaround ... this was just a custom image slider captcha that needed a backend verification

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function:

```
function sliderCaptcha(string $url) {
    // Create a stream
    $opts = [
        "http" => [
            "method" => "POST",
            "header" => "Accept: application/json\r\n" .
                "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
        ]
    ];
    
    // DOCS: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    
    // Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
    // DOCS: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    return $result;
}

$url = 'api/Captcha';

$captcha = sliderCaptcha($url);
```

Answer (score -2):

use curl for php

```
<?php
function sliderCaptcha($url, $data){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$result = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
if ($result == '200') {
    echo $result";
} else {
    echo "Fail!";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. It doesn't even send the same headers as the original code, so how could this really be a drop-in?

Comment: i figured out a workaround btw thanks for trying to help